# Who/What am I if I'm known as an animal but I'm really not one?

Tags: riddle

> You drag me around but I feel no pain
>
> I am an animal without a tail but the real me has a tail
>
> My left and right eyes are abused
>
> But I really don't care; I'm not really alive!
>
> I'm useful and better than that old pad
>
> For that old pad can really get people mad
>
> I only respond when you give me a material I like
>
> For I hate hard materials
>
> Those are things I don't like!
>
> I come in different ways
>
> I can have a blue tooth
>
> But don't worry, that's no cavity!
>
> It's a healthy tooth; it can help people in many ways!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are

> a mouse (in the computer sense, not the animal).

*You drag me around but I feel no pain*

> You move the mouse around on your desk, but it doesn't feel pain because it's not alive.

*I am an animal without a tail but the real me has a tail*

> A computer mouse doesn't have a tail (at least not literally - it might have a wire), but real living mice do.

*My left and right eyes are abused*

> By much pressing and clicking on them.

*But I really don't care; I'm not really alive!*

> Yep.

*I'm useful and better than that old pad*
*For that old pad can really get people mad*

> I hate laptop touchpads!

*I only respond when you give me a material I like*
*For I hate hard materials*
*Those are things I don't like!*

> A mouse works best on a soft mat, rather than a hard surface.

*I come in different ways*

> Different kinds of mouse (wireless, optical, ball).

*I can have a blue tooth*
*But don't worry, that's no cavity!*
*It's a healthy tooth; it can help people in many ways!*

> A Bluetooth mouse can be useful.

---

**Feedback section**

The riddle would have been more challenging without the "blue tooth" lines, since this is too explicit a link to Bluetooth and the world of computers; once we're looking for something computer-related which has the same name as an animal, the field of possibilities is really very small. The "blue tooth" clue was what I immediately zeroed in on, since it was a strange-looking clue with probably few possible interpretations. At first I was trying to think of something blue and sharp, assuming "tooth" was a metaphor, but then I quickly realised what it really meant.

Comment: Hmph! I thought this would be hard! Correct! :D

Comment: Ah, 5 minutes quicker than me. I would leave my answer, though, as the explanations I gave are a tad different. :)

Comment: I *hate* the old mouses. I much prefer my laptop touchpad.

Comment: @AbAppletic Added feedback section to show why it wasn't really that hard. Also, why "animal without a tail"? Real mice do have tails!

Comment: @randal'thor I was talking about the computer mouse

Comment: "The real me **has** a tail"

Comment: @AbAppletic Aha, I misinterpreted "real". Editing ...

Answer (score 6):

Are you:

> Wireless mouse

You drag me around but I feel no pain

> The mouse is mechanical and does not really feel pain.

I am an animal without a tail but the real me has a tail

> A wireless mouse does not have a cable and thus no tail. The real mouse has a tail.

My left and right eyes are abused

> The left and right buttons of the mouse are constantly pressed.

But I really don't care; I'm not really alive!

> It is mechanical.

I'm useful and better than that old pad

> It is much more comfortable to use a mouse than the laptop's touch pad.

For that old pad can really get people mad

> The touch pad is not really convenient and can be touched/pressed accidentally, resulting in undesired effects.

I only respond when you give me a material I like

> When you put the mouse on some materials, it doesn't respond well - for example, if I put it directly on the bed.

For I hate hard materials

> Sometimes hard materials can also make the mouse not responsive enough.

Those are things I don't like!

I come in different ways

> There are many different designs.

I can have a blue tooth

> The mouse can be a bluetooth mouse or a USB mouse.

But don't worry, that's no cavity!

> The bluetooth is not a cavity, it is a connection type.

It's a healthy tooth; it can help people in many ways!

> Bluetooth can be really useful.

Comment: Correct, but not necessarily a Wireless mouse... I don't know which answer to choose, yours or @rand's

Comment: You have a nice angle of looking into it, but by "No tail" I meant it doesn't have a tail. LITERALLY :P

Comment: Too slow, but +1 anyway :-)